# Ruby Fibers and faye

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, faye, fibers

I have simple script with EventMachine, Fibers and faye

```
require "faye"
require "em-synchrony"
require "hiredis"
require 'redis'
require 'redis/connection/synchrony'

faye = Faye::Client.new 'http://localhost:9292/faye'
redis = Redis.new

EM.synchrony do

  faye.subscribe('/event_1') do |message|
    Fiber.new do
      puts "Event 1 start"
      user_id = redis.hget 'myhash', message.client_id
      puts "Event 1 finish"
    end.resume
  end 

  faye.subscribe('/event_2') do |message|
    Fiber.new do
      puts "Event 2 start"
      user_id = redis.hget 'myhash', message.client_id
      puts "Event 2 finish"
     end.resume
  end # subscribe

end #EM.synchrony
```

event_1 comes first, event_2 next to it (very small interval)
When i run it and event's fired. I always have this output:

```
Event 1 start
Event 2 start
Event 2 finish
```

Thats all.
Where is Event 1 finish?
What i'm doing wrong?

**UPD:** If i remove asynchrones removing `require 'redis/connection/synchrony'` all works great. But i need this asynchrones.

ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use Synchrony ConnectionPool.